# Twitter.com requests Error

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I do not use requests library often so I do not know how to debug this error. I am using some code from github.
https://github.com/ashleycoxley/twitter-analytics-export

The error is with the .get function.

```
tw_url = "https://twitter.com/"
session = requests.session()
first_req = session.get(tw_url)
```

Error Message:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

It's probably simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can**

add `verify = False` to:

```
first_req = session.get(tw_url, verify = False)
```

**Explanation**

For some reason your Python code doesn't trust the SSL certificate presented by `twitter.com`. FWIW, it might not be Twitter at all, who your code is talking to.

Most likely this is due to your computer's configuration of trusted [Certificate Authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) and/or something in between you and Twitter (e.g. your ISP) interfering with your communication.

And `verify=False` simply means "I don't care if the server I connect to, is not a real Twitter.com just let me connect to it".

Comment: That did it! Your explanation sounds right, I am on very restricted network. Thank You!